# mysql_query not returning result to select call

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a mysql_query call and it is not returning a result. There are results in the table it should be seeing. 
The issue is with the last line of this code block. If anyone has seen this issue or sees a mistake let me know. I have also hard coded a varible into the query with no change in the result.

```
while($tempArray=mysql_fetch_array($myListings, MYSQL_NUM))
{//construct link that will post data to url for proper use later
    ?>
<tr>
<td>
<a href="bis_list.php?srchValue=<?php echo $tempArray[0] ?>"><?php echo $tempArray[1]?></a>
</td>
</tr>   

<?php 
}

?>
</table>
<?php 

if($title=$_GET["srchValue"])
{

    echo $title;
    //$title
    $sql="SELECT * FROM biz_categories WHERE category_id= $title";
    $biz_ids=mysql_query($sql, $con);
```

Comment: `category_id=AUTO` --- What datatype `category_id` is? Please guys let him understand his mistake, not feed with ready solution

Comment: `mysql_error()` or running the query yourself is also a good indicator to the problem.

Comment: category_id is one of the fields of table biz_categories. AUTO is one of the values that would be in the category_id field. Also even if I put $title in place of AUTO, as it's supposed to be it still does not work. zerkms... if you know whats wrong it would help to just tell me. I have been messing with it for hours.

Comment: no errors thrown/displayed when mysql_error() used.

Comment: @aaron burns: it is string. What do you know about strings?

Comment: i don't understand. is category_id the same type as biz_categories... I have had 3 classes in php and this was part of an extra credit thing but its past due now. I just want to know why it does not work.

Comment: @aaron burns: what do you know about string data type in php and mysql?

Comment: i know nothing..about strings pertaining to php.. I do not not what you are getting at. We went over php to get at the client server concept of programming. Not the nuances of the language.

Comment: @aaron burns: oh my god, you don't even know that strings should be enclosed in quotes?

Comment: enclosing category_id in quotes does nothing to solve this problem. I had already tried that and many variations. That is why I posted. How would you write the query.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10890/discussion-between-aaron-burns-and-zerkms)

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-literals.html --- please read it

Comment: http://sergworks.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/why-stackoverflow-sucks/

Comment: http://zelcs.com/this-is-why-stackoverflow-sucks/ http://fskrealityguide.blogspot.com/2009/02/stackoverflow-sucks.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"SELECT * FROM biz_categories WHERE category_id='$title'"

This is the correct formatting needed. I swear I tried it that way already.

Comment: -1. That leaves your application open to sql injection attacks.

Comment: sql injections are not to be considered here. It is homework.

Comment: Homework questions like this aren't going to help anyone, so I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: Funny.... It helped me. Why are people with 10,000+ rep always so uppity on SO.

Comment: Because homework is a sad excuse to neglect prudence. It's like saying you can put a loaded gun in your pants with the safety off if you stay indoors. The real world doesn't work like that.